# What is wrong with this slideshow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation, slideshow

I was trying to do a image slideshow but I failed every attempt. This is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/row0sp6w/) link. You may notice that black square under the pictures, I do not know how to remove that, if I try removing, the whole slideshow will stop working. Also, this is how it looks in my html:

[image: that black square]...

HTML Code:

```html
<div id="section1">
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sheet">
      <h1> Latest.</h1>
      <hr/>
      <div class="bss-slides demo1" tabindex="1" autofocus="autofocus">
        <figure>
          <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/medium.jpg" width="100%" />
          <figcaption>"Medium" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/thomashawk/14586158819/">Thomas Hawk</a>.</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado.jpg" width="100%" />
          <figcaption>"Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/stuckincustoms/88370744">Trey Ratcliff</a>.</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/monte-vista.jpg" width="100%" />
          <figcaption>"Early Morning at the Monte Vista Wildlife Refuge, Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/davesoldano/8572429635">Dave Soldano</a>.</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/sunrise.jpg" width="100%" />
          <figcaption>"Sunrise in Eastern Colorado" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/35528040@N04/6673031153">Pam Morris</a>.</figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
          <img src="http://leemark.github.io/better-simple-slideshow/demo/img/colorado-colors.jpg" width="100%" />
          <figcaption>"colorado colors" by <a href="https://www.flickr.com/photos/cptspock/2857543585">Jasen Miller</a>.</figcaption>
        </figure>
      </div>
      <!-- // bss-slides -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is helping ?

```
/* if you want */
.bss-slides {
    background: transparent;
}
/* align slides with container */
.bss-slides figure {
    margin: 0;
}
/* button on top of it */
.bss-fullscreen { 
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The black background is appearing because of the background property for the .bss-slides class. Remove the background. And than align the pictures.